# How reduce (<th>) width of datatable column in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable

Actually I use primefaces 3.5.
I want to reduce the  width for **specific** column in a datatable

it doesn't work:

```
<p:dataTable  styleClass="myTable" ......................>
<p:column width="5" headerText="verylargeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee">
</p:column>
```

Comment: Did you try setting width on the table but not directly `column`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, but it will not reduce the size of a column to be less than the headerText width. You can set the header to use multiple lines when the text is too large, but it only works if there are spaces in the headerText. That won't help with your example because there are no spaces. The CSS for that option is below:

```
.ui-datatable thead th {
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

In other words, I am not sure how you can reduce the size of a column to less than a word length.

Comment: my header text have space,I want to reduce a fixed size for my column always keep complete words in a line.